# Auto increment wont update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

just created a form that saves the filename into an SQL database.

The thing is that when I ad the ID column(Auto increment) into the SQLDatabase the form stops to save my filename, but as soon I delete the ID row, it begins to save.

Dont know whats the problem.

this is some of my code

```
 <?php  



     if(isset($_FILES['file_name'])) {
     $file_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file_name']['name']); 
      //Writes the information to the database 

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('$file_name')") ; 
      }

     //Retrieves data from MySQL 
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files") or die(mysql_error()); 
     //Puts it into an array 

     ?>
```

And my database has two columns file_id and file_name
but as I just wrote, the file_id wont work =/

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to change your SQL query to this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files` (`file_name`) VALUES ('$file_name')") ;
```

With more than one column, you need to name which column you want the `$file_name` string to be saved in if you're not going to enumerate every column in the table. Then your auto-increment should work fine.

In fact, the problem isn't with auto-increment, it's with your SQL syntax. You should check your queries for errors by saving the return value from `mysql_query` and checking if it returned `false`. If it did, call `mysql_error` to determine the error message.

Comment: In the OP's query, he was supposed to provide each value for every column, but only provided one. This way allows MySQL to provide a default value for the auto-increment.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ID` is auto_inc, you don't need to include it in your script anywhere.

I think the problem is because you don't specify in your query what fields to put the values in.

Change this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files` VALUES ('$file_name')") ;
```

To something like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `files` (`YOURFIELD`) VALUES ('$file_name')") ;
```

Comment: That was actually the problem, I tried that first, but I seems like i wrote it wrong :)

Thanks a lot friend